# Wrong output in use of vector of struct

Tags: c++

There is no syntax error, But compiler give a wrong data at the end !
What's wrong ? The Test file is a simple txt file that have 12 data in my case, 12 number that list one by one in each line :
    122
    135
    148
    156
    178
    189
    256
    114
    125
    136
    630
    360

```
int main(){

int a;
const int b = 4;

int Index = 0;
int Counter = 0;
char Heights[255];

ifstream input("Test.txt");

struct stru{
string Data[b];
};

stru sam;
vector<stru> event;

if(input.is_open()){
    while(input) {
    input.getline(Heights, 255);
        if(input) {
            Index = (int) Counter/b ;
            sam.Data[ Counter-(b*Index)] = Heights;
                if ( Counter%b == 0 ){
                event.push_back(sam);
                }
              Counter += 1;
        }
    }
cout <<"Event size: " << event.size() <<endl;

cout <<event[0].Data[11]<<'\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

the result of " event[0].Data[0] " must be 122 That it is right !
But in other hand, As u see in txt file the last data is 360 and i expect that the result of " event[0].Data[11] " be 360, But it's wrong. Output show 114. What's wrong ?

Comment: I recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure none of your structs have `Data[11]` ever set. Especially when the length of array in your struct is `4`.

Comment: *There is no syntax error* -- This has nothing to do with whether your program will run correctly.  Your program could still have logic bugs.

Comment: Indeed that the length of array is 4 but in the next step i use of vectors, could i convey my mean ?

Comment: `event[0].Data[11]` is undefined behavior.  Anything could happen.  Including output of 114.

Comment: @AA360c `event` is a vector, but each `event[k].Data` is still a four-element array.

Comment: @AA360c `cout <<event[0].Data[11]<<'\n';` -- This says to go to the first item in `entry`, and then output the 12th entry in the `Data` array.  There is no 12th entry -- so does this make sense to you?  You need to understand fully what each line does, as this should have been obvious as to what is happening.

Comment: @Eljay  `sam.Data[ Counter-(b*Index)] = Heights` . it will be fill up i think.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- As u can see my data that i list first, The `12th` number is `360`. its going through array and vector as last number. am i wrong ?

Comment: @AA360c do not look at only the first element of _sam_ going out of its _Data_, iterate in _sam_ and  _Data_, look my answer

Comment: @AA360c -- There is no need to think of this with such complication.  `Data` is an array of 4 items.  You are accessing the 12th item in `Data`, and that is out-of-bounds.  Accessing items out-of-bounds can give you anything, including crash your program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- Sry mate but i'm a beginner, Can u explain more why u called it out of bound when i define it ! There is just 12 number and i define it and give to to program as first and end item. First term is `122` and the last one is `360`. Why it's out of bounds ?

Comment: @AA360c your management of the index in _Data_ and to push in _event_ is probably wrong, I edited my answer, see it

Comment: @AA360c `const int b = 4;...string Data[b];` -- What do you see there?  You see that `Data[b]` is really `Data[4]`.  That is an array, with valid indices of `0,1,2,` and `3`.  There is no `Data[11]` that is valid.  In C++, when you access an array out-of-bounds as you did, anything can happen.  It is that simple of a concept -- I don't know how much simpler to explain it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- Thank you mate, I only just got your mean, I was wrong. You have my thanks. :x

Comment: @Eljay -- You have my thanks. I got it now. :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said in remark `cout <<event[0].Data[11]<<'\n';` has an undefined behavior, your check is wrong and better to replace that line with something like :

```
for (int i = 0; i != event.size(); ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
    cout << "event[" << i << "].Data[" << j << "] = " << event[i].Data[j] << endl;
}
```

Doing that the result is :

```
Event size: 3
event[0].Data[0] = 122
event[0].Data[1] = 
event[0].Data[2] = 
event[0].Data[3] = 
event[1].Data[0] = 178
event[1].Data[1] = 135
event[1].Data[2] = 148
event[1].Data[3] = 156
event[2].Data[0] = 125
event[2].Data[1] = 189
event[2].Data[2] = 256
event[2].Data[3] = 114
```

---

Furthermore your management of the index in *Data* and to push in *event* is *very* strange I think

```
    while(input) {
    input.getline(Heights, 255);
        if(input) {
            Index = (int) Counter/b ;
            sam.Data[ Counter-(b*Index)] = Heights;
                if ( Counter%b == 0 ){
                event.push_back(sam);
                }
              Counter += 1;
        }
    }
```

must be replaced by

```
while(input) {
  input.getline(Heights, 255);
  if(input) {
    sam.Data[Index] = Heights;
    if (++Index == b) {
      event.push_back(sam);
      Index = 0;
    }
  }
}
if (Index != 0)
  event.push_back(sam);
```

Doing that the result is :

```
Event size: 3
event[0].Data[0] = 122
event[0].Data[1] = 135
event[0].Data[2] = 148
event[0].Data[3] = 156
event[1].Data[0] = 178
event[1].Data[1] = 189
event[1].Data[2] = 256
event[1].Data[3] = 114
event[2].Data[0] = 125
event[2].Data[1] = 136
event[2].Data[2] = 630
event[2].Data[3] = 360
```

Comment: @burno -- There it is, That's it. Ty mate. :X

Comment: @burno -- Thanks again :x

Comment: @burno --- Why `event[0].Data[11]` exist, Whilst `Data[b]` have just `4` member as declared before? As i expected `Data[11]` should not be exist, But it is and show the last one as it is `360` !!!

Comment: @AA360c the access to `event[0].Data[11]` is invalid, you go out of `event[0].Data`, the result is unspecified, this is not because you *seem* able to access it that this is the valid.

Comment: @burno -- As my last question, What we mean exactly by saying "undefined behavior" or " unspecified" ? Well, if compiler can not understand it or anything else, it must be shown an error, Idk, Something else except that the true value. In my case, It shows the true value exactly. Even i test it with 512 and even more data number, It's work correctly !!!

Comment: @burno -- Sry mate, Im a beginner, Tell somehow that i can get it :D

Comment: @AA360c (I am bruno, not burno ;-) ) when an array is sized 4 and you go at the index 11 you go out of it, you cannot know what will append == undefined/unspecified behavior, may be you will have a crash, may be not and you will access to *something*, you cannot know, all depends on the code produced by the version of the compiler you use (and only that one) and on what you did before in memory. To summary : **do not do that**

Comment: Omg, I'm sorry , that was miss click/type :), I appreciate your help. I got it now, Really thanks bro.